# Convert function with std::array of doubles as argument or the doubles separately as arguments

Tags: c++, type-conversion, c++14, std-function

I want to make a method `convert` that takes a general function `bar` (can be an `std::function`, `lambda`, `functor`,...) and converts it to an `std::function<double(std::array<double, 3>)>`. The function `bar` can either be:

- a function taking `std::array<double, 3>` as an argument and returning a `double`. In this case, `convert` is not difficult to write:

code:

```
template<typename F>
std::function<double(std::array<double, 3>)> convert (F& bar)
{
    std::function<double(std::array<double,3>)> bar_converted = bar;
    return bar_converted;
}
```

- a function taking three separate `doubles` as an argument and returning a `double`. Also in this case, `convert` is not too difficult to write:

code:

```
template<typename F>
std::function<double(std::array<double, 3>)> convert(F& bar)
{
    std::function<double(std::array<double,3>)> bar_converted;
    auto array_bar = [bar]( std::array<double, 3> x)->double{ return bar(x[0], x[1], x[2]); };
    bar_converted = array_bar;
    return bar_converted;
}
```

The problem is that I do not have a clue how to combine these two `convert` methods, or whether this is even possible?

Comment: Do you have a moment to talk about our lord and savior, SFINAE?

Comment: This is going to need a lot of plumbing, or you can just use boost to inspect the parameter types: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/function_traits.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Max mentioned, the solution is to use [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) to check what arguments `F` can be called with:

```
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

/* Aliases to shorten the following code */
using BarArray = std::array<double, 3>;
using BarFunction = std::function<double(BarArray)>;

template <typename F>
/* Check whether F can be called with BarArray and returns double */
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::result_of_t<F(BarArray)>, double>, BarFunction>
convert(F bar)
{
    return bar;
}

template<typename F>
/* Check whether F can be called with three doubles and returns double */
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::result_of_t<F(double, double, double)>, double>, BarFunction>
convert(F bar)
{
    return [bar](BarArray x) {
        return bar(x[0], x[1], x[2]);
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works! I only had to define `is_same_v` myself (as [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same), but without the `inline`), since it is also a c++17 helper variable.

Answer (score 5):

I'll start with how I would write this in C++17:

```
template<typename F>
std::function<double(std::array<double, 3>)> convert(F&& f) // <== NB: forwarding ref
{
    if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<F&, std::array<double, 3>) {
        // direct case
        return std::forward<F>(f);
    } else {
        // unpacking case
        return [f=std::forward<F>(f)](std::array<double, 3> arr) {
            return std::apply(f, arr);
        };
    }
}
```

In C++14, you don't have  `if constexpr`, [`is_invocable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable), or [`apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply). The first can be achieved by just doing tag dispatch (you invoke a helper function with either `std::true_type` or `std::false_type`) and the other two can be implemented in C++14 just fine, and are really useful helper functions that you will likely need for lots of other things anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately I am restricted to C++14, since my compile is g++ 5.4.0.